# How do I expand nested bundles when deriving bundles in Bevy?

Tags: rust, bevy

In [this example](https://bevy-cheatbook.github.io/programming/ec.html), the following code is provided.

```rust
#[derive(Bundle)]
struct PlayerBundle {
    xp: PlayerXp,
    name: PlayerName,
    health: Health,
    _p: Player,

    // We can nest/include another bundle.
    // Add the components for a standard Bevy Sprite:
    #[bundle]
    sprite: SpriteSheetBundle,
}
```

However, the #[bundle] tag seems to be missing in the latest release. Is there any way to provide similar functionality in 0.4.0? I know I can use "commands.with" and "commands.with_bundle" but I don't see an alternative to "spawn_batch" without manually flatting the struct to combine bundles.

Comment: Using the latest Bevy release (0.5.0) your example is compiling fine for me. What is the actual error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was temporary and specific to an early build of Bevy, and is now resolved. The solution is to upgrade.

Comment: So will it work in ðe latest version, 0.7.0+?